# How is this matrix expression equivalent?

Tags: matrices

I have two matrix expression that are supposed to be the same which I don't get.

First one

$\begin{pmatrix}N_sE & \\N_pE &\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} w\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -v_s\\-v_p\end{pmatrix}  $

Second one

$\begin{pmatrix}N_sE & -v_s\\N_pE &-v_p\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} w \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}  $

How is this the same?

Thanks!

Comment: As currently written, these equations aren't equivalent - you need to drop the minus sign from one copy of the "v"s. Macrophage's answer drops it from the second time they come up, but either works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left hand side of the first equation is a matrix multiplied by a number so you multiply each entry of the matrix. Hence, the systems of equations represented is
$$\begin{cases}
&w\cdot N_sE=-v_s\\
&w\cdot N_pE=-v_p\\
\end{cases}
$$

The left hand side of the second equation is multiplication of two matrices. So you multiply row by column and get the following system of equations
$$\begin{cases}
&w\cdot N_sE+1\cdot v_s=0\\
&w\cdot N_pE+1\cdot v_p=0\\
\end{cases}
$$

Simple rearrangment shows that the two systems of equations above are equivalent.